# Does UIScrollView only work on a view controller that is embedded in a Navigation Control?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Does UIScrollView only work on a view controller that is embedded in a Navigation Control?  The reason I ask is because I have a UIViewController that has a UISCrollView to show all the content that exceeds beyond the view.  This ViewController is displayed from a push segue from a TableViewController, which is embedded into a Navigation Controller.

Everything worked fine until I tried to change the push segue to a modal seque instead, which thus removed the view from being embedded into a Navigation Controller.

All the content loads just fine but it won't scroll.  I have added an outlet and tried programmatically setting the contentSize and scrollEnabled properties but still nothing. It won't scroll any more and I can't figure it out.  I have been searching on the net but I can't find an answer.

Outlet:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.contentSize  = CGSizeMake(320, 900);
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Try setting it back to a push segue momentarily to make sure nothing else is broken, and to verify that's the only change.

Comment: You know what it wasn't working in the Push segue either. I thought it was but apparently it was only scrolling the extra space that was taken away by the Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put the UIScrollView in another empty UIView in order to get it to work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize  = CGSizeMake(320, 900);
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `another empty UIView in order to get it to work`

This was the key for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of posts indicating issues with setting the contentSize of a scrollView in viewDidLoad.  Try moving it to viewDidAppear.

Comment: It definitely works after the push segue but it's still not working after the modal segue. I guess I'll just use a push segue for now.